# How would I convert a css3 animation to a video?

Tags: video, css

How would I convert a css3 animation to a video?

Comment: You want any online tools for it or you want to create your own app for it?In case of app what server side language do you prefer..

Answer (score 1):

Use a screencast recorder. For example, Camtasia.